# Install old version of packages wih an old version of R

Tags: r, shiny, package, shiny-server, devtools

I have to deploy a Shiny app to a Shiny Server that already has apps running on it, and this sevrer uses an old R version, the version 3.4.0 (2017). There are also a lot of packages already installed on the server, each with a given version.

To deploy my app I have to make sure that the app I developped still works with this version of R and the versions of the packages already installed. (I know that a clean way to deal with this type of thing is to use packrat, but I can't use it here because I can only drop files on the sevrer, I can't open R in the server to run packrat::restore() and packrat::on() )

To do so I have installed R 3.4.0 on my computer, and I now want to install all the packages my code needs, but using the versions matching the shiny server environnment. And for many of the packages the corresponding version is not the latest version in the CRAN.

I know that it is possible to install a given version of a package with the function `install_version` of the package devtools. The problem is that I can't install devtools. When i run `install.packages("devtools")` this shows up :

```
also installing the dependencies ‘colorspace’, ‘vctrs’, ‘munsell’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘pillar’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘gtable’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘lazyeval’, ‘shiny’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘askpass’, ‘clisymbols’, ‘gh’, ‘purrr’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘yaml’, ‘processx’, ‘fansi’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘crosstalk’, ‘openssl’, ‘brew’, ‘commonmark’, ‘stringr’, ‘xml2’, ‘praise’, ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘covr’, ‘desc’, ‘DT’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘glue’, ‘git2r’, ‘httr’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rversions’, ‘testthat’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
            binary source needs_compilation
vctrs        0.1.0  0.2.3              TRUE
pillar       1.3.1  1.4.3             FALSE
scales       1.0.0  1.1.0              TRUE
tibble       2.1.1  2.1.3              TRUE
shiny        1.3.2  1.4.0             FALSE
ggplot2      3.1.1  3.2.1             FALSE
gh           1.0.1  1.1.0             FALSE
purrr        0.3.2  0.3.3              TRUE
yaml         2.2.0  2.2.1              TRUE
processx     3.3.0  3.4.2              TRUE
fansi        0.4.0  0.4.1              TRUE
htmlwidgets    1.3  1.5.1             FALSE
openssl        1.3  1.4.1              TRUE
xml2         1.2.0  1.2.2              TRUE
usethis      1.5.0  1.5.1             FALSE
callr        3.2.0  3.4.2             FALSE
cli          1.1.0  2.0.2             FALSE
covr         3.2.1  3.4.0              TRUE
DT             0.5   0.12             FALSE
ellipsis     0.1.0  0.3.0              TRUE
git2r       0.25.2 0.26.1              TRUE
httr         1.4.0  1.4.1             FALSE
pkgbuild     1.0.3  1.0.6             FALSE
rcmdcheck    1.3.1  1.3.3             FALSE
roxygen2     6.1.1  7.0.2              TRUE
rversions    1.1.0  2.0.1             FALSE
testthat     2.1.1  2.3.2              TRUE
devtools     2.0.2  2.2.2             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?
y/n:
```

And wether I chose yes or no, a lot of things are printed on the console but it eventually doesn't work when I try to load the package :

```
> library(devtools)
Error in library(devtools) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

Can someone tell me another way to install devtools in R 3.4.0 so that i can load all the other packages with the version I need ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try the [versions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/versions/versions.pdf) package?

Comment: With this package I have the following error whenever I try to install a package :

`> install.versions('shinyjs', '1.0')`
`Error in if (!all(df$available)) { : `
  `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Hmm I don't know. Otherwise, you can try to install an old version of devtools: [devtools archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/devtools/).